# Add Product to Session of Wishlist and not delete the session like now

Tags: php, jquery, session, addition

I got a problem with my shopping cart wishlist sessions. I add with a button an article to wishlist in form of an session array when i click another icon to whishlist he removes me the clicked item before an delete the session of the item selected before.
here is my **js** code to grab values for session:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".addButton").on("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var button = $(this);
        var parent = button.parent();
        var wlproducturl = parent.find("input[name$='.id']").val();
        var wlproduct = parent.find("input[name$='.name']").val();

            $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "../assets/wlscript.php",
        data : { wlproduct : wlproduct, wlproducturl : wlproducturl },
        success : function(data) { 
        $('div#resultwish').html('<div class="alert alert-success in fade" ><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>You added '+wlproducturl+' '+wlproduct+'\'s to your wishlist.</div>');
        }
    }); 

        // alert("Add article with id = " + idArticle + " and name = " + nameArticle);
    });
});
```

This is my wlscript php file:

```
<?php
session_start();


$p = trim($_POST['wlproduct']);
$q = trim($_POST['wlproducturl']);
$orders[$p] = $q;
$_SESSION['orders'] = $orders;
?>
```

And so I output the selected items:

```
                              <?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION['orders']);
?>
```

So how can I add new item to session  without deleting the old one add a product more to wishlist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe simply because you are overwriting $orders each time, with your actual code:

```
<?php
session_start();

$p = trim($_POST['wlproduct']);
$q = trim($_POST['wlproducturl']);
$orders[$p] = $q; // UNAWARE IF $_SESSION['orders'], OR $orders ALREADY CONTAIN SOMETHING...
$_SESSION['orders'] = $orders; // ... AND THEREFORE ALL IS OVERWRITTEN.
?>
```

Maybe this ?

```
<?php
session_start();

// if (session_is_registered("orders")) // CAREFUL, OBSOLETE SINCE PHP 5.4.0
if (is_array($_SESSION['orders']))
{
$orders = $_SESSION['orders']; // RETRIEVING WHAT HAS PREVIOUSLY BEEN STORED
}


$p = trim($_POST['wlproduct']);
$q = trim($_POST['wlproducturl']);
$orders[$p] = $q; // THIS NOW ADDS TO EXISITNG
$_SESSION['orders'] = $orders;
?>
```

Comment: he gives me an internal server error 500 back when i add to whishlist in wlscript.php do you know what it is about ?

Comment: Not at all. This code should not interfere with Apache. It could come from the copy/paste... Did you try writing the added lines instead of copying them?

Comment: What version of PHP do you use? session_is_registered might be obsolete. In this case, try : if (is_array($_SESSION['orders']))...

Comment: Great man really thanks always awesome here on stackoverflow the user support big thanks man really session was obsolete was working with if (is_array($_SESSION['orders'])) ;)